# GPO: Is there a way to apply NTFS permissions dynamically?

Tags: permissions, group-policy, ntfs

I would like to create a GPO that sets NTFS permissions on a set of folders and files.

```
Computer Configuration => Policies => Windows Settings => Security Settings => File System
```

and then add a groups like

```
DOMAIN\%MyEnvVar%_GroupName
```

It seems not possible. However there may be some hidden feature or a way I am not aware of. Any ideas on this? Thanks in advance

Comment: This confuses me.  Why are you referencing domain group with environmental variables?  That's... weird, and probably not working because a group with that name doesn't exist.  (I can't imagine a reason why domain groups with those names would exist, at least.)

Comment: I agree, it is weird. But that's the AD constelation here. There are special groups for each server and an environment variable that contains this information...

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, you want to apply NTFS permissions to allow access to files/folders on `someserver` by `domain\someserver_groupname`?  It sounds to me like the easiest way would be with a GPO that links a startup script.  Not as good as a normal GPO, but I don't know any other way to get the server hostname into your group name for your the NTFS permissions.